# MongoDB: Find all documents except those where a date range condition matches

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Requirement: I want a collection of all customers who `did not perform the "View" event in last 5 hours`.

Data:

```
{
    name: "Sheldon",
    events: [
        {
            event: "View",
            timestamp: "timestamp equivalent to 10 hours ago"
        },
        {
            event: "Some other event",
            timestamp: "timestamp equivalent to 8 hours ago"
        },
        {
            event: "View",
            timestamp: "timestamp equivalent to 2 hours ago"
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: "Leonard",
    events: [
        {
            event: "View",
            timestamp: "timestamp equivalent to 10 hours ago"
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: "Howard",
    events: [
        {
            event: "View",
            timestamp: "timestamp equivalent to 2 hours ago"
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: "Raj",
    events: [
        {
            event: "Some other event",
            timestamp: "timestamp equivalent to 6 hours ago"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried out the following, but it always returns `"Sheldon"` (possibly because the other event ends up satisfying the criteria?).

```
q.where({ 
    $and: [
        {
            'events': { 
                $not: { 
                    $elemMatch: {
                        event: "View",
                        timestamp: {
                            $gte: "timestamp equivalent to 5 hours ago"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

What can I do so that only documents for `"Leonard"` and `"Raj"` are returned?

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465634/mongodb-query-on-nested-array-elements) once.

Comment: you can check out (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/) for more details.

Comment: @TanmayBaranwal my example query is equivalent to the one in your link, does not work as expected because there's another event that satisfies the criteria.

Comment: Do  you have dates in ISO format ? Why not update your post with actual dates ? It will make it easy for people trying to answer and test your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get users how has not visited in last 5 hours. you can try it

```
db.collectionName.find({
    events: { 
        $not: { 
            $elemMatch: {
                event: "View",
                timestamp: {
                    $gt: ISODate("2017-03-29T05:12:37.420Z") // equivalent to 5 hours ago
                }
            }
         }
    }
}, {name: 1})
```

This query `returned` only documents for `Leonard` and `Raj` for your given example

**N.B:** Like your query but I used `find` instead of `where`, no need to use `$and` and used `$gt` instead of `$gte`

**Tested for documents.**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58db886e4b9e731aaefa9820"),
    "name" : "Sheldon",
    "events" : [ 
        {
            "event" : "View",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-03-29T00:09:18.723Z")
        }, 
        {
            "event" : "Some other event",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-03-29T02:10:04.492Z")
        }, 
        {
            "event" : "View",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-03-29T08:11:02.196Z")
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58db886e4b9e731aaefa9821"),
    "name" : "Leonard",
    "events" : [ 
        {
            "event" : "View",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-03-29T00:11:23.084Z")
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58db886e4b9e731aaefa9822"),
    "name" : "Howard",
    "events" : [ 
        {
            "event" : "View",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-03-29T08:11:02.196Z")
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58db886e4b9e731aaefa9823"),
    "name" : "Raj",
    "events" : [ 
        {
            "event" : "Some other event",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-03-29T04:10:42.972Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

**After apply my query result:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58db886e4b9e731aaefa9821"),
    "name" : "Leonard"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58db886e4b9e731aaefa9823"),
    "name" : "Raj"
}
```

Comment: How is this different from the one I have mentioned in the question?

Comment: No need to use `$and` and used `$gt` instead of `$gte` other than your query should be working. Tested using your data :) @hiteshspac

Comment: @ShaishabRoy The query u have written does not gives the output as desired. Its retutning the whole dataset. Can you please check!

Comment: I asume `timestamp` is `Date type` so if `timestemp` is `Date type` then it should be work. I tested @RohitRai